# why doesn't youtube api javascript code work inside jquery document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Youtube Javascript API code outside jQuery ready function: http://jsbin.com/umituf/1

Inside jQuery ready function: http://jsbin.com/umituf/2

I would like to use jQuery because when the video is stopped (`even === 0`) and `loadmore()` method is called, I want to write a ajax call in jQuery to go back to the server and fetch more video id's so they can be further passed to the `cuePlaylist(...)` method.

Why am I not able to mix jQuery and the API and How can it be done?

Comment: Try using $.getScript - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: thats for making the ajax call. I want to be able to put the code inside `document.ready()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions need to be defined in the global scope.

http://jsbin.com/umituf/3

Edit for clarification:
The youtube api script looks for those particular functions on the global scope. The api script does not have access to the scope that is created within the document.ready callback.

Comment: great. so can I put jQuery's .ajax() methods in the global space

Comment: You can, just  make sure anything that access the DOM does so after the elements exist. I suggest placing javascript before the closing body tag if possible.

Answer (score -1):

youtube api js-code, that you attach to page, use global context. You can put your code into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
});
```

But in the end you must write this (*) string.

After this  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function will be able from global context